# Create a new live tile that doesn't default to the regular tile size when jumped to the Start screen

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, live-tile

In my app, when creating a live tile, you must define the tile size you want to use for your live tile (because not all three tile sizes will be a live tile). However when you're jumped to the Start screen with the newly created live tile, the tile size always defaults to the regular tile size (even if the live tile's size is set to either small or wide).

Is there a way for the live tile size created on the Start screen to be of the size the user chooses? That is, if they picked wide, then the live tile on the Start screen defaults to wide, so users wouldn't need to manually change the tile size.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is impossible and even it it where possible with some hack: The you does not expect it and will probably be annoyed.

Many apps have only big live tiles (which I find quite annoying) and default to display their logo on smaller tiles - as a WP user this behaviour is expected and understood, so go with it.

If you want to help your users, do it like True Calendar 8 which display a preview of the lives tiles in the settings menu.